# Flutter Inspector does not show in View>Tools Windows

Tags: flutter

I newly start to learn Flutter. In some projects, Flutter Inspector and Flutter Outline do not show.

#### It seems in this

[image]

#### It does not seem in this

[image]

#### why

I searched on the Internet but can not find an answer. Please help me. Thanks.

#### Version info - Flutter Doctor

[image]

I write this issue to Flutter on GitHub

[GitHub | Flutter - IntelliJ Issue Topic: Flutter Inspector does not show in View>Tools Windows #6804](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6804)

Comment: Did you try check then uncheck "Open Flutter Inspector view on app launch" in File->Settings->Languages & Frameworks->Flutter->App Execution?

Comment: I controlled it, and it is checked. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Answer (score 2):

My issue is solved. You can check this

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6804#issuecomment-1605015037